# How to set a default value for a property of an entity that depends on count of previous ones

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an entity that I'd like to have a property which holds an integer that gets value by count of previous entities created in the same day.

Let's say I have BooksOrder class. When a new BooksOrder created and saved to Db, I'd like it's property `int DailyCount` to be equal `BooksOrders.Where(bo => bo.Created.Day == DateTime.UtcNow.Day).Count() + 1`

Where would be best place to implement it? `OnModelCreating` definition of DbContext?
If there, how?

Or in migration definition file, by editing `Up()` method and define `defaultValueSQL` with an SQL query? I did use it with `GETDATE()` Sql function before for a DateTime property, but not like in this case.

Third way I think of is to override SaveChanges() method of DbContext:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    var AddedBooksOrders = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(e => e.State == EntityState.Added && e.Entity is BooksOrder)
        .Select(e => e.Entity).Cast<BooksOrder>();

    foreach (var abo in AddedBooksOrders)
    {
        abo.DailyCount = BooksOrders.Where(bo => bo.Created.Day == DateTime.UtcNow.Day).Count() + 1;
    }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

My guess is this wouldn't work because it won't let me query DbSet BooksOrders within DbContext class definition itself(if not static, we need an istance, which doesn't exist at the time of this definition)

Did you guys run into a simmilar problem? I'd be happy to know if it's possible and how.

Thanks

Comment: I would look at keeping this derived value updated asynchronously to the rest of the system, e.g. every time a books order was placed or amended, I would queue an event which could be subscribed to by a thread which would then recalculate and update the Daily running total. This could also be debounced, e.g. could limit the update to a max of once per minute etc. if near real time isn't needed.

Comment: @StuartLC Well, asynchronous setting of that value does not help me in that situation, I need to get that almost instantly. Yet all alternatives that comes to my mind requires me to do some SQL function/stored procedure intervention, which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I didn't want to get into Stored Procedure business, well at least integrated with EF Code First and I'm happy with the solution actually.
First I added that property to my entity:

```
public int DailyCount { get; set; }
```

then, Package Manager: `add-migration "WithDailyCount"`. Lastly, in migration definition added stored procedure code to `Up()` method (and the one that deletes it in `Down()` method)

```
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("myDb.BookOrders", "DailyCount", c => c.Int(nullable: false));

        Sql(string.Format(@"                
                    CREATE PROCEDURE [myDb].[DailyCountIncrement]
                    AS
                    BEGIN
                        DECLARE @DCountPlusOne int
                        SET @DCountPlusOne .....More SQL code here to read and increment count goes here
                        SELECT @DCountPlusOne 
                    END"));
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropColumn("myDb.BookOrders", "DailyCount");
        DropStoredProcedure("myDb.DailyCountIncrement");
    }
```